# Order of sequence of elements with different cardinalities in a doctype

Tags: xml, dtd, doctype

I'm creating a doctype for XML files I'm working with to simplify their validation. However, I'd like to express something and I don't know how.

I have `<test>` elements. These elements can have up to one `<description>` tag, but must have 1+ `<node>` child, and any number of `<argument>` tags. However, I'd like it to be possible to specify them in no particular order. For instance, this snippet:

```
<test>
    <node>foo</node>
    <argument>baz</argument>
    <description>bar</description>
</test>
```

should be a valid `<test>` representation.

The first obvious answer that came to my mind was this:

```
<!ELEMENT test (description?, node+, argument*)>
```

but it's my understanding that the comma operator will require the elements to be present in [the precise order they're specified](http://www.w3schools.com/dtd/dtd_elements.asp).

How can I make a doctype that will not have this requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why DTD was abandoned in favour of XML Schema - DTD isn't expressive enough, even for simple cases like this.

I stronly suggest you forget DTD, and use a Schema.

Answer (score 1):

Use [RELAX NG](http://relaxng.org/compact-tutorial-20030326.html#id2815185) instead of DTDs.

Comment: I'm using JDOM, and a quick Google search didn't show any way to validate using such a description.

Comment: I don't know much about JDOM, but what about the [Jing](http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/jing.html) RELAX NG validator?

Comment: I suppose it would validate separately, but it might be better if the solution at least somehow integrated with JDOM. DTDs at least had the advantage that JDOM automatically validates XML files against them. (Also, you should add @username before your comment, like @zneak, if you want me to be notified that you replied.)

Comment: @zneak, if you need something that works with JDOM only (no other dependencies), then I suspect that you're out of luck. XML DTDs don't support what you want (interleaving).

Comment: At least that's "good" to know. I'll see if it's worth it to move to Schema or RELAX NG. You get a +1 from me.

Comment: RelaxNG is a nice way of doing a schema. Unfortunately, the tool support is lousy, and without that, it's not much practical use.

Comment: @skaffman, "lousy" is a little harsh, IMHO. [Jing, Trang, and Emacs nXML-mode](http://www.relaxng.org/#software) are three great tools (all written by James Clark). And [MSV](http://java.net/projects/msv/) is not bad (I just noticed that the MSV website has been reorganized since my last visit, and I can't find any downloads at the moment).

Comment: @nzjn: I'm not saying the tools themselves are lousy, I'm saying the support *for* those tools is lousy, compared with the universal and ubiquitous support for XML Schema.

Comment: @skaffman: OK, point taken. In some of the tools that I use (GNU Emacs and Oxygen XML editor), the RELAX NG support is very good.